# ATG- Issue in sending email through atg scenario

Tags: email, nullpointerexception, atg

I have a requirement to send an email after registration of a new user my ATG application.

I have created a template jsp and created a scenario in ATG for that.

I also configured **config/atg/scenario/IndividualEmilSender.properties** with below key-value-

```
contextPathPrefix=/teststore
siteHttpServerName=localhost
siteHttpServerPort=8080
```

And **/config/atg/userprofiling/email/TemplateEmailSender.properties** as:-

```
$class=atg.userprofiling.email.TemplateEmailInfoImpl
mailingName=Your Mailing
contextPathPrefix=/teststore
messageSubject^=/atg/dynamo/service/SMTPEmail.defaultSubject
messageFrom^=/atg/dynamo/service/SMTPEmail.defaultFrom
contentProcessor=/atg/userprofiling/email/HtmlContentProcessor
fillFromTemplate=true
templateURL=/NewUserRegistered.jsp
loggingDebug=true
```

But getting following exception-

```
ERROR [ScenarioManager] Error while processing individual timer message InstanceTimerMessage[17000001,/TestStore/RegistrationScenario.sdl,NewMembers,3,in 1 mins]; rolling back the transaction java.lang.NullPointerException
    at atg.scenario.action.SendEmail.createTemplateEmailInfo(SendEmail.java:193)
    at atg.scenario.action.SendEmail.execute(SendEmail.java:526)
    at atg.process.ProcessManagerService.executeAction(ProcessManagerService.java:14001)
    at atg.process.ProcessManagerService.takeIndividualTransition(ProcessManagerService.java:13408)
    at atg.process.ProcessManagerService.receiveIndividualTimerMessage(ProcessManagerService.java:12732)
    at atg.process.ProcessManagerService.receiveMessage(ProcessManagerService.java:11416)
    at atg.process.ProcessManagerService.receiveMessage(ProcessManagerService.java:11341)
    at atg.dms.patchbay.ElementManager.deliverMessage(ElementManager.java:316)
    at atg.dms.patchbay.InputPort.onMessage(InputPort.java:190)
    at atg.dms.patchbay.InputDestination.onMessage(InputDestination.java:397)
    at atg.dms.patchbay.InputDestinationConsumer.processMessageDelivery(InputDestinationConsumer.java:501)
    at atg.dms.patchbay.InputDestinationConsumer.runXATransactions(InputDestinationConsumer.java:371)
    at atg.dms.patchbay.InputDestinationConsumer.run(InputDestinationConsumer.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) 

10:34:32,527 INFO  [ScenarioManager] DEBUG [message]: message ID:170000 failed a total of 1 times so far 
10:34:32,543 ERROR [MessagingManager] An error occurred while MessageSink with nucleus name "/atg/scenario/ScenarioManager" was receiving a Message from input port "IndividualTimers": javax.jms.JMSException: CONTAINER:atg.process.ProcessException; SOURCE:java.lang.NullPointerException 
10:34:32,558 INFO [ScenarioManager] DEBUG received message on port IndividualTimers message: jms-msg:ID:170000 
10:34:32,558 INFO  [ScenarioManager] DEBUG [message]: not processing message ID:170000 after 1 failed delivery attempts
```

Please help to resolve this!
Thanks!

Comment: Which version of ATG are you using?

Comment: Are you, by chance, adding any attachments to your email?

Comment: No I am not attaching anything.

Comment: @Buddha, please stop creating so many new tags related to [tag:atg].  The [tag:atg] tag has less than 120 questions.  There is no way that any of these extremely specific tags are going to actually *help* categorize questions at this point in time.  In fact, adding so many tags is going to make it *actively harder* for the small number of ATG users to actually find relevant questions.

Comment: @Charles I just thought that people would use the tags if they exist, and the tags I created are various important parts of atg. however what you said is valid that they are not useful at this time. I will be more careful in future.

Comment: @Buddha, the main problem is that people are *really bad* at picking tags, and tags have no hierarchy.  Frequently, someone will see that their specific tag exists, use it, and use no others.  This is a big problem in low-activity tags, because nobody will be watching the plethora of tiny, specific tags.  Questions will get lost, and people won't get the answers they need.  It's always best to wait for a high degree of activity before beginning to create tags for components and concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a `NullPointerException` because your `DefaultEmailInfo` is not configured correctly.

Have a look at the chapter around [Sending Targeted E-mail](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35319_01/Platform.10-2/ATGPersProgGuide/html/s1103sendingtargetedemail01.html) as well as the [SendMail action](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35319_01/Platform.10-2/ATGPersProgGuide/html/s2016sendemailaction01.html) in the documentation.

It is likely that you are missing one or more of the required configuration changes.